# Llenar array con mysqli_query

Tags: php, json, mysqli, datatables

Quiero llenar un array con una consulta que hago de una tabla pero no se como darle el formato correcto.

Este es mi PHP:

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM registros2";
$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas con la consulta");
while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{
array_push($c,
$reg['id'],$reg['cliente'],$reg['metodo_pago'],$reg['hora'],$reg['fecha_entrega']);
}
```

Cuando imprimo el resultado me sale asi:

```
[
   "100",
   "Carlos Luna",
   "Credito 30D",
   "14:15:00",
   "2018-05-09",
   "104",
   "sadfsadf",
   "Contado",
   "12:32:00",
   "2018-06-18"
]
```

Y necesito que el formato sea asi:

```
{
   "data": [
     [
       "100",
       "Carlos Luna",
       "Credito 30D",
       "14:15:00",
       "2018-05-09"
     ],
     [
       "104",
       "sadfsadf",
       "Contado",
       "12:32:00",
       "2018-06-18"
     ]
   ]
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar este código

```
     $c = [
         'data' => []
     ];
     $consulta="SELECT * FROM registros2";
     $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas con la consulta");
     while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
     {
         array_push($c['data'],[$reg['id'],$reg['cliente'],$reg['metodo_pago'],$reg['hora'],$reg['fecha_entrega']]);
     }
```

Me cuentas si te funcionó bien :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer que cada registro sea un array.  Intentalo asi:

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM registros2";
$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas con la consulta");
$c = array('data' => array());
while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{
array_push($c['data'],
array($reg['id'],$reg['cliente'],$reg['metodo_pago'],$reg['hora'],$reg['fecha_entrega']));
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: De nada, veo que has hecho varias preguntas, pero no has marcado ninguna como correcta.  Es una buena practica aceptar las respuestas que te han ayudado para que la comunidad te siga ayudando.